# Ajax / Laravel response is returning the data but also the executed query

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, security

I am currently trying to get to grips with Laravel, I have a page that sends an ajax get request (using jquery) to retrieve data from the database. This is executing fine except that when I look at network->response in a browser the data being returned also includes the query that is being executed my concern is for security, I don't want users to be able to see this information is there a way to prevent this? (It maybe that this is only for debugging purposes which is fine, but I can't find anything about this online), please can anyone help advise?

Here is an example of one of the queries that the ajax calls:

```
Route::get('/task/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);
    return Response::json($task);
});
```

Thanks in advance

[Screenshot from opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrxSH.png)

Comment: can you screenshot sample of what you mean? or what browser are you using?

Comment: `return $task`?

Comment: I owe y'all an apology! Please see below!

Answer (score 0):

Another developer was using my machine yesterday, for debugging and added the following code:

AppServiceProvider.php

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    var_dump([
        $query->sql,
        $query->bindings,
        $query->time
    ]);
});
```

without telling me, so apologies to everyone!